# UIScrollView Jerky Scrolling

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I have a big scroll view. I just wish to scroll around the scroll view with fixed steps on every button press. However when I write the following code the scroll view scrolling is very jaggy. Can someone explain why?

```
CGPoint lstructCurrentPoint = self.objScrollView.contentOffset;
lstructCurrentPoint.x += 400;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             [self.objScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(lstructCurrentPoint.x,
                                                                                lstructCurrentPoint.y,
                                                                                self.objScrollView.bounds.size.width,
                                                                                self.objScrollView.bounds.size.height)
                                                            animated:NO];
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished)
                         {
                         }];
```

I do not use the animated:Yes arguement because I need custom scroll speeds between the different contentOffsets.

Answer (score 1):

when you update your scroolview content frame while scrolling with an animation is like you try to update something that is in the past that is already changed... (probably is not the best explanation :D )

try with this in your animation option:

```
options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
```

Comment: Could you better explain what is the behavior that you get?

Comment: Please see the ScrollView Programatic Scroll Project at this location . On the project, you can see very smooth scrolling with the slider value close to 60. But anything like 200+ make the scroll jerky. (dropbox.com/sh/rdldvliuio6ebrg/OTjUJFj_rl)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try using

```
[self.objScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(lstructCurrentPoint.x, lstructCurrentPoint.y,self.objScrollView.bounds.size.width,self.objScrollView.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
```

instead of using this within UIView animation function.

Comment: I don';t do the animated:Yes because I have a scroll view which I wish to scroll to different contentOffsets at different rates. The default scroll view animated can only do it as two speeds. I wish to specify different speeds for travelling to different content offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
[self.objScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMame(lstructCurrentPoint.x, lstructCurrentPoint.y) animated: YES];
```

instead of scrollRectToVisible.

Comment: I do not wish to use the animated:Yes thing. Thats the whole reason i am using the UiView animate method.

Answer (score 0):

scrollRectToVisible animated is an animation by itself.

With your current code, you are trying to animate the animation.

Hence it is jerky.

Just use to scroll the rect to visible:

```
[self.objScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(lstructCurrentPoint.x,lstructCurrentPoint.y,self.objScrollView.bounds.size.width,self.objScrollView.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have the animated argument set to NO. So I don't think this is the case of animation within the animation. Also I need to do custom times for the animations and hence I do not wish to do the animated argument to yes because that can scroll stuff in only two speeds.

Comment: In that case, I'd try this: figure out the contentOffset for the rect to be visible, setContentOffset as the rect's origin (or where ever you want the origin to be positioned in the scrollView's visible rect) in the animationWithDuration block.

Answer (score 0):

No one can properly answer your question without knowing what content you have in the scrollView.

However, you can find out what is causing this yourself.

Profile the app on your device. This will open Instruments. Select the Core Animation tool.

When the app is running scroll the view so that instruments captures the data.

Now the Time Profiler section will tell you exactly what is taking a long time. Fix this and you'll have smooth scrolling.

Comment: Please see the ScrollView Programatic Scroll Project at this location . I already did try the instruments and time profiler but I don't seem to understand what causes this. Actually on the project, you can see very smooth scrolling with the slider value close to 60. But anything like 200+ make the scroll jerky. Link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rdldvliuio6ebrg/OTjUJFj_rl

Comment: Hmm... it's hard to tell as I don't have an iPad to test on. Looking at the time profiler though it's flagging up the line `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFilePath:path]`. Could you cache that image instead of calling it each time? Also, is the image the correct size for display or is it being resized?

Comment: 1. You may try this on the simulator. Its the same behavior on a device or a simulator. 2. The image is not being resized. 3. [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFilePath:path] this function does not impact anything as I have tried doing the [UiImage imageNamed] thing too. 4. The image is not being resized.

Comment: 1. I am running on simulator. However, the simulator is many times faster than an iPad. 3. With either method you are still loading the image from disk every time. Instead store the UIImage in a property or NSArray if you need multiples. So that you are caching the image instead of loading it from disk every time.

Comment: Tried what you suggested. I load the tile once and then reused the same tile everywhere. Its the same result. Actually, I do not think that this is caused by the image or the tiles.

Comment: You need to profile it yourself and see what is taking the time. What is making the animation slow, etc...